# Why is my GridLayout not working? (JPanel in JFrame)

Tags: java, swing, layout, grid, jpanel

So I got bored and wanted to make a little commando prompt in Java. At the moment I'm remaking the ls-command from the Bash-Shell on Linux. Since the command prompt itself is just a small window I have to show the result of the ls-command in a separate window, I thought a little list with all the files in the directory (which is what ls does) popping up on the right of the prompt would be nice. I just called it sideWindow and made it JFrame, because I failed when I tried to make it a Dialog. As tutorials suggest, I add a JPanel and set its Layout to Grid, having only one column because I want the sideWindow to basically show a list of all the files in a directory, one file under the other. So the number of rows depends on the number of files in that directory, and so does the size of the Frame.

But for some reason that window doesn't show at all, I didn't even set a location where it would show up yet. I bet it's a really stupid mistake coming from my inexperience but I just can't figure it out.

My code might be too confusing and stupid, but I hope someone can tell what my mistake is.  The important part  is the ls-method I guess.

Thanks in Advance!

Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.URI;
import java.io.*;


public class CommandPrompt extends JFrame implements KeyListener{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1231231;
JTextField eingabe = new JTextField();
Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
JLabel path = new JLabel();
String pathName = "/";

public CommandPrompt() {
    setTitle("Colamanndo");
    setSize(402,88);
    setResizable(false);
    setLayout(null);
    setBackground(Color.black);

    eingabe.setToolTipText("Ich mag Cola");
    eingabe.setSize(399,30);
    eingabe.setLocation(1,1);
    eingabe.setBackground(Color.black);
    eingabe.setForeground(Color.green);
    eingabe.addKeyListener(this);
    add(eingabe);

    path.setText(pathName);
    path.setToolTipText("Tu ich wirklich");
    path.setSize(399,30);
    path.setLocation(3,24);
    add(path);

    setVisible(true);
 }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new test();
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == 10) {
        String comm = eingabe.getText();
        eingabe.setText("");
        idCommand(comm);
    }

    if (e.getKeyCode() == 38) {
        eingabe.setText("Es klappt");
        //Eigentlich aus .txt Datei letzten Befehl lesen
    }
//  System.out.println(e.getKeyCode());
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void idCommand(String cText) {
    try {
    StringBuilder command = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder parameters = new StringBuilder();
    parameters.append("");

    for(int i = 0;i<cText.length();i++) {
        command.append(cText.charAt(i));
        if (cText.charAt(i) == ' ' || i == cText.length()-1) {
            if (command.toString().charAt(i) == ' ') {
                command.deleteCharAt(i);
            }               
            if (cText.length()>i+1) {
                for (int j=i+1;j<cText.length();j++) {
                    parameters.append(cText.charAt(j));
                }
            }   
            System.out.println("Command identified: /" + command.toString() + "/");
            System.out.println("Parameters identified: /" + parameters.toString() + "/");
            //command durch liste schicken
            if (command.toString().equals("exit")) {
                System.exit(0);
            } else
            if (command.toString().equals("netflix")) {
                desktop.browse(new URI("http://www.netflix.de"));
            } else
            if (command.toString().equals("vampire")) {
                desktop.browse(new URI("http://www.netflix.com/WiPlayer?locale=de-DE&movieid=70212855"));
            } else
            if (command.toString().equals("chrome")) {
                desktop.browse(new URI("http://www.google.com"));
            } else
            if (command.toString().equals("shutdown")) {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sudo shutdown -s now");
            } else
            if (command.toString().equals("gedit")) {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("gedit");
            } else 
            if (command.toString().equals("cd")) {
                cd(parameters);
            } else
            if (command.toString().equals("ls")) {
                ls(parameters);
            }
            break;
            }
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            }

}

public void ls(StringBuilder parameters) {
    try {
        File directory = new File(pathName);
        String[] files = directory.list();

        //sideWindow is the frame that shows the files
        //in that directory
        JFrame sideWindow = new JFrame();
        sideWindow.setSize(files.length*30,100);
        sideWindow.setName("Files in" + pathName);
        JPanel filePanel = new JPanel();
        sideWindow.add(filePanel);
        filePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(files.length,1));
    //  filess.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);

        if (parameters.toString().equals("-a")) {
            for (int i = 0;i<files.length;i++) {
            filePanel.add(new JLabel(files[i]));
            }

        } else {
            for (int i = 0;i<files.length;i++) {
                if (files[i].charAt(0) != '.') {
                    filePanel.add(new JLabel(files[i]));
                }
            }
        }
    //  pack();
        add(sideWindow);
        filePanel.setVisible(true);
        sideWindow.setVisible(true);    

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

public void cd(StringBuilder parameters) {
    //falls die parameter leer sind, wird pathname zurückgesetzt
    if (parameters.toString().equals("")) {
        pathName = "/";
    }
    //falls bei path name am ende ein / ist, wird es entfernt   
    if (pathName.charAt(pathName.length()-1) == '/') {
        pathName = pathName.substring(0, pathName.length()-1);
    }
    //falls am anfang vom parameter kein / ist, dann wird eins hinzugefügt
    if (parameters.toString().charAt(0) != '/') {
        pathName += "/";
    }
    //die parameter werden an pathname rangehängt
    pathName += parameters.toString();
    path.setText(pathName);
}

public void addCommand(String commandName, String commandCode, boolean isBash) {

}
```

}

Comment: Your main method calls new test(); what is that? You probably want to do something like new CommandPrompt();

Comment: Oh yeah the class was called test first, because when I started this program I didn't know what to do. Just renamed right before posting so you guys could more easily differentiate between the windows. Forgot to change the main-method, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting this as an answer as I cannot comment (<50 rep).

It would a lot more helpful if you could post only the relevant part of the code, since it makes it easier for us guys to find a problem.

Also, I would suggest using BoxLayout if you just want to display a single column instead of Grid Layout(from your question).

Also, since sideWindow is a JFrame I don't think it can be added to another JFrame using the add method. To do that, make sideWindow a JPanel and make the necessary changes. Or if you want it to open in a new window, make a new class for it and then call it's constructor to start it up.

Comment: Thanks, that really helped. I use BoxLayout now and made an extra class lsWindow extending JFrame.

Comment: Happy to help :) It might help you to check out the Java Documentation for JFrame and JPanel. Also an upvote wouldn't hurt  :D need 1 rep to comment

Comment: @namsnath This is an answer, so there is really no need to say you don't have enough rep to comment.